# Dealing with prolonged comment debates

Tags: discussion

So a user asked a question here:

[Why isn't the Fed funds rate greater than interest rate on loans to the pubic](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/why-isnt-the-fed-funds-rate-greater-than-interest-rate-on-loans-to-the-pubic)

And the comment conversations he's having with people are getting very long, which generally isn't the purpose of the comments, but there doesn't seem to be a feasible way of stopping them, since the asker is having trouble understanding everyone's answers, for one reason or another. How do we deal with situations like this? I imagine it might eventually lead to some not-so-good tensions arising if it keeps up.

It might not even be a problem though; for the Econ SE, long conversations might be necessary and productive. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a usual phenomenon around many SE sites, even though it goes against "official" policy and suggestions. The system offers automatically a sensible alternative, "move this conversation to chat", which is indeed the place to exchange comments which in most cases tend to be in essence clarifying attempts rather than a true contrast of opinions and point-of-views.

As for possible tensions, this is one of the reasons why moderators are here for. Flag the thread for moderator attention writing also a message like "please monitor, tensions ahead" when you sense that verbal friction builds up.

Comment: I suppose not much to do besides that then.